# WordPress: Archive page, filtered by year and category

Tags: wordpress, filter, categories, archive

I got a problem and can't find any solution for an archive page where you can sort and filter by category and year at the same time.

Comment: Problem solved: http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=17432